# JavaScript print values in array with function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code snippet in JS

```js
names = [{name: "A"}, 
     {name: "B"}, 
         {name: "C"}, 
         {name: "D"}];

var returnNames = function(item, index) {
    var p = names[index].nome;
   return p;
}

names.forEach(returnNames);
```

I would like to print all the names according to the index but when I call the function it doesn't return any value
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `map` instead of `forEach`. Also, don't mention `names` in your function. Use `item.name`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the console.log within the function. Also, `nome` is misspelled.

```
var returnNames = function(item, index) {
    var p = names[index].name;
    console.log(p);
}
```

Comment: When it takes out the console.log it doesn't print anything. What I want to do is when calling the function to return the names without needing to use console.log.

Answer (score 0):

```js
names = [{
    name: "A"
  },
  {
    name: "B"
  },
  {
    name: "C"
  },
  {
    name: "D"
  }
];

var arr = names.map(({name})=>name);
console.log(arr);
```

Must be the spelling mistake

Comment: When it takes out the console.log it doesn't print anything. What I want to do is when calling the function to return the names without needing to use console.log.

Comment: @Rodrigo Does the updated solution match your expectation?